# Benefits on @staticmethod in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-methods

I have a simple question : why using the staticmethod decorator on static methods ? You can make static methods that don't have the "self" parameter, without this decorator.

When using python2, it was necessary :

```
>>> class A:
...  def p(object_to_print):
...   print(object_to_print)
... 
>>> A.p('test')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method p() must be called with A instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

However, if I do the exact same thing using python 3, it will works fine.

Why using a decorator if it works fine without it ? If the first parameter is not named self, it is quite obvious it is a static method. The only reason I can see is to get clearer error in cases of misuse…

Is there any reason for this behaviour in python 3 ?

Thanks :)
palkeo.

Comment: The `@staticmethod` decorator is available in Python 2 as well.

Comment: And a static method can be used on instances too, not just on classes.

Comment: I know it is available, and for python 2 you have to use it : if you don't you get the error I mentioned. However, what is the reason it is possible not to use it in python 3 ? That's more my question.

Comment: Because the notion of an *unbound* method was removed in Python 3. It didn't offer anything useful in Python 2. So you just get the original function in Python 3 instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try to call this method with an instance of `A` and you'll get an exception:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.p('test')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: p() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Because the argument is considered as the instance itself:

```
>>> a.p()
<__main__.A object at 0x7f9f60f56048>
```

However, if the method is decorated with `staticmethod`, it works as expected:

```
>>> A.p('test')
test
>>> a.p('test')
test
```

Comment: Ok, that's another difference. Any other reason ? Especially for the difference of behaviour between the two versions of python.